# ExecuteNonQuery hangs

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, executenonquery

I have below query in ASP.NET MVC and its working fine in my local system.

```
using (OracleConnection conn = AppConn.Connection)
{
    conn.Open();

    comm = new OracleCommand(@"insert into integration.file_log(file_name,file_type,file_status) values(:file_name,:file_type,-1) returning file_id into :file_id", conn);

    comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("file_name", file_name));
    comm.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("file_type", "GROUP-ADD"));

    OracleParameter file_id = new OracleParameter("file_id", OracleDbType.Int64);
    file_id.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    comm.Parameters.Add(file_id);

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

    file_auto_id = Convert.ToInt64(file_id.Value.ToString());
}
```

But when I moved the same to server the site getting hang at

```
comm.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

When I checked the table the data is inserting but at debug mode the control is lost at `comm.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Comment: I think the issue is caused due to a `lock` since you have a transaction which is awaiting some response. You need to close it or rollback the transaction.

Comment: @ViVi but hw it work from my local system

Comment: That I'm not sure. I had a similar issue. That was due to a pending transaction. Or the connection may already be open. Debug and check.